# data.matrix() when character involved

Tags: r, matrix, character, data.table

In order to calculate the highest contribution of a row per ID I have a beautiful script which works when the IDs are a numeric. Today however I found out that it is also possible that IDs can have characters (for instance ABC10101). For the function to work, the dataset is converted to a matrix. However `data.matrix(df)` does not support characters. Can the code be altered in order for the function to work with all kinds of IDs (character, numeric, etc.)? Currently I wrote a quick workaround which converts IDs to numeric when ID=character, but that will slow the process down for large datasets.

Example with code (function: extract the first entry with the highest contribution, so if 2 entries have the same contribution it selects the first):

Note: in this example ID is interpreted as a factor and data.matrix() converts it to a numeric value. In the code below the type of the ID column should be character and the output should be as shown at the bottom. Order IDs must remain the same.

```
tc <- textConnection('
    ID   contribution   uniqID      
   ABCUD022221       40           101  
   ABCUD022221       40           102 
   ABCUD022222       20           103
   ABCUD022222       10           104
   ABCUD022222       90           105
   ABCUD022223       75           106
   ABCUD022223       15           107
   ABCUD022223       10           108        ')

df <- read.table(tc,header=TRUE)

#Function that needs to be altered
uniqueMaxContr <- function(m, ID = 1, contribution = 2) {
  t(
    vapply(
           split(1:nrow(m), m[,ID]), 
           function(i, x, contribution) x[i, , drop=FALSE]
           [which.max(x[i,contribution]),], m[1,], x=m, contribution=contribution
          )
  )
}

df<-data.matrix(df) #only works when ID is numeric
highestdf<-uniqueMaxContr(df)
highestdf<-as.data.frame(highestdf)
```

In this case the outcome should be:

```
    ID   contribution   uniqID      
   ABCUD022221       40           101  
   ABCUD022222       90           105
   ABCUD022223       75           106
```

Comment: Why do you need data.matrix? Purely for size constraints? If that's true, I feel "Mr. data.table solution" is lurking in the shadows. @mnel? :)

Comment: I don't really have any constraints, so data.table is an option.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Others might be able to make it more concise, but this is my attempt at a data.table solution:

```
tc <- textConnection('
    ID   contribution   uniqID      
   ABCUD022221       40           101  
   ABCUD022221       40           102 
   ABCUD022222       20           103
   ABCUD022222       10           104
   ABCUD022222       90           105
   ABCUD022223       75           106
   ABCUD022223       15           107
   ABCUD022223       10           108        ')

df <- read.table(tc,header=TRUE)

library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(df)
setkey(dt,uniqID)

dt2 <- dt[,list(contribution=max(contribution)),by=ID]

setkeyv(dt2,c("ID","contribution"))
setkeyv(dt,c("ID","contribution"))

dt[dt2,mult="first"]

##               ID contribution uniqID
## [1,] ABCUD022221           40    101
## [2,] ABCUD022222           90    105
## [3,] ABCUD022223           75    106
```

### EDIT -- more concise solution

- You can use `.SD` which is the subset of the data.table for the grouping, and then use `which.max` to extract a single row.

in one line

```
dt[,.SD[which.max(contribution)],by=ID]

##               ID contribution uniqID
## [1,] ABCUD022221           40    101
## [2,] ABCUD022222           90    105
## [3,] ABCUD022223           75    106
```

Comment: Made it a bit more concise. -- no need for the merging.

Comment: `data.table` is so powerful, but it really needs a syntactical front end.

Comment: Spend enough time with it, and it starts to make sense. Read @MatthewDowle's answers and edits on SO -- that is how I learn!

Comment: I know it's possible to learn data.table like that and that's what I am doing, but it's not optimal that you need to spend so much effort. The threshold for beginners is pretty high.

Comment: @Roland Would a common tasks wiki help, showing syntax for various tasks? The closest we have to that currently is `example(data.table)`. The tip at the top of `?data.table` suggests to run `example(data.table)` at the prompt and work through it. Have you done that? And have you read all 3 vignettes? The first section of the FAQ is meant to be read in order. `data.table` is not meant to be learnt from just S.O., I agree! When you say it's a lot of effort to learn, how long has it taken you so far? Interested to hear more about your learning experience so we can improve it.

Comment: @Matthew Dowle Well, I admit that I am mainly investing time to learn the syntax, when I actually have to use the package. I read through `example(data.table)` but comments are sparse and I tend to only look for what I need for the specific task thereby not remembering other useful commands. I believe it would be easier to wrap my head around the syntax if I completely understood the logic behind it, which I haven't so far. A wiki might be useful, but I would prefer if you concentrated on further improving the help files, because those are integrated in the IDEs, e.g., RStudio.

Comment: @Roland I honestly don't know how to improve the help files. They're more detailed and verbose than R's own help files for example. If you have any suggestions I'll gladly add them. Users have made many useful contributions and those have been reflected already. `.SD` has quite a large paragraph in `?data.table` dedicated to it, for example.

Comment: @Roland It might help to know also that `data.table`'s syntax is one reason _why_ it's fast. For example, not passing a function in `j` is part of it; in `data.table` it's a plain expression (no closure). Wrapping syntactic (functional) sugar around it would slow it down, I think, and reduce syntactic goodness such as compound queries (London R presentation slide 22).

Comment: @MatthewDowle I was presuming that spending time meant reading the (verbose and helpful) help  files / FAQ and intro. The SO answers and comments refine usage and learn neat tricks and or more optimal ways of doing things

Comment: @mnel Might have been a missing "And" in your comment then: "[And] read Matthew Dowle's answers and edits on S.O. ..." I thought Roland had got the impression he had to trawl through S.O. to learn the package. From his comments I suspect he has dipped in and out of `?data.table` and the vignettes, when needed, and has therefore increased his _elapsed_ learning time. Rather than assigning several hours in one block to work through the examples slowly.

Comment: @Matthew Dowle You are exactly right and I think this is what you can expect from the majority of users. I know, it would be best to invest some time specifically in learning the tools. But due to time constrains this is often not done. Furthermore, it's easiest to learn by just using the tool. The problem with `data.table` is that there are many other tools for the same purpose and only if efficiency becomes an issue, you turn to `data.table`. And suddenly you have to learn a new syntax framework, which is based on coding issues R users normally do not (need to) think about.

Comment: @Matthew Dowle I forgot to add: But still, we love `data.table`. Keep up the good work. :)